# MongoDB's count() incorrectly returns 0 if a query is given

Tags: mongodb, database

Our database is currently running and everything seems to fine. I wanted to do some statistics so I did some standard calls. Basically I wanted the number of some specific data.

First some basic calls to show you that there actually is data in the database.

```
> db.files.count()
814639

> db.files.find({"migrated":true})
{ "migrated" : true, "filename" : "bleh",... }
...
```

So clearly there's data, and the call returns it. Now I want to find out how many results there is, but I get this:

```
> db.files.count({"migrated":true})        
0
```

And I did this too:

```
> db.files.find({"migrated":true}).count()
0
```

Is there anyone who has any idea why this could be happening?

The versions is:

```
> db.version()
1.8.1
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps a corrupt database? Have you tried to run --repair/repairDatabase() ?

Comment: We've had some recent crashed, but after each time we've run --repair before starting it. Problem is that it's live, so I can't really take it down. Or am I mistaken in believing that repair can't be performed on a live database?

Comment: For what its worth, a --repair will basically do a dump and import of your data.  If any records are corrupt, they will be discarded during this process.

Comment: @Bryan: With the example I gave, do you think it could fix it?

Comment: I am not even sure if that is the problem, I was just building on the comment left by Sentinel regarding repairs.

Comment: Even if the DB was corrupt, there is no reason why a find() that returns records should have 0 count.  I would post this to the mongodb-user list and see if Dwight or Eliot can explain.  I would try a repair first just in case that helps.

Comment: I have the same experience with mongodb 2.0.1 (In a Linux 32 bits VM).  I have a cursor with a large query and timeout in false since many days ago and at the same time I am querying the information in the console. db.collection.count() returns the correct count, the find returns elements after a find, but find({...}).count() doesn't work anymore. It was running until one hour ago.

Comment: Is it the same case with find().count()...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while, but I'm closing this now. But it was a corrupt database. Had to manually move all the items from one database to a new one since a backup stopped when it found the corrupt data, and valid data afterwards wasn't being backed up.

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that this question is related to the following bugs:

- [Interrupted count query returns 0 as count result](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3678)
- [count command returns zero in some error cases rather than reporting an error with ok:false](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2291)

In my case (mongodb 2.0.1) was related to database corruption. See [find().count() bug?](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/40eac4c9a38ce687/72785f77ebe8d4b4?lnk=gst&q=count%200%20find#72785f77ebe8d4b4)