# Why does my Collection.find().count() always returns 0 at client?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Collection containing 1.7 million documents.  When executing `count()` on server side console I get correct results.

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.postcodes.find().count();
1737697
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

Whereas at the browser console I always get zero for `count()` and for `findOne()` returns `undefined`.

`insecure` package has not been removed. And `count()` and `findOne()` are working for other smaller Collections.Not much code is present at the moment.  Apart from the default html, js, css. Only a couple of line of code is present.  I have `model.js` living in its own folder (neither in Server nor in Client) that has

```
PostCodes = new Mongo.Collection('postcodes');
Hello = new Mongo.Collection('hello');
```

All the Collections I have at the moment is

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.getCollectionNames();
[
        "hello",
        "meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration",
        "parttimejobs",
        "postcodes",
        "system.indexes",
        "users"
]
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

Package I have are

```
autopublish                  1.0.3  
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.2.69  
insecure                     1.0.3  
meteor-platform              1.2.2  
twbs:bootstrap               3.3.5
```

Sample document

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.postcodes.findOne();                 
{                                                       
        "_id" : ObjectId("559933dc4a8617644069fa5b"),   
        "postcode" : "AB10 1AB",                        
        "latitude" : 57.149079,                         
        "longitude" : -2.096964,                        
        "county" : "",                                  
        "district" : "Aberdeen City",                   
        "ward" : "George St/Harbour",                   
        "constituency" : "Aberdeen North",              
        "loc" : [                                       
                -2.096964,                              
                57.149079                               
        ]                                               
}
```

Comment: No way to know without seeing the code.

Comment: I have updated my question with all collections and model.js

Comment: Did you removed auto-publish package??

Comment: I have not created channels yet. So, autopublish is still present.

Comment: You probably ask for count when there is no collection on client-side yet, you would have to create some waitOn function in your routes waiting for collection to be ready

Comment: After doing a few tests it happens that the behaviour of the application under very heavy load caused by `insecure` with a large collection is somewhat inconsistent and wacky. Have you tried loading the page, waiting 5 or 10 minutes, then coming back and checking the count? Firefox took forever to load in my tests.

Comment: yea..did some test, when there is small amount of data then `PostCodes.find().count();` gives me correct result. In case of huge data its keep on loading the page...still now....

Comment: Instead working with such a huge amount of rows (you have to know that the complete collection will by synced to minimongo when starting the app) you have to make a better approach and write your own publisher method. So you can e.g. enable post-loading data etc. If you need to work with the complete dataset you should prefer to write a Meteor.method which you call from client.

Comment: maybe your db is corrupt: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034345/mongodbs-count-incorrectly-returns-0-if-a-query-is-given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many mentioned, this was due to large volume of data.  Expected results are returned after removing autopublish and creating a channel.

```
Meteor.publish('postCodesChannel', function(){
    return PostCodes.find({postcode: {$regex: /B14 6B[DE]/}});
});
```

Browser console now returns appropriate values

```
>PostCodes.find().count();
2
```

Comment: Thus, protip: Do not send gigabytes of data on each page load.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to do `count()` very early on when the app launches, it does not seem like the data is ready (due to the large amount that needs to be loaded).

If you just need the count, I would recommend using a Meteor Method and asynchronously get the count, so you don't have to wait for the the client subscription to be ready for 1.7 million documents.

Below is an example of a method:

On the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSomeCollectionCount: function () {
    return someCollection.find().count();
  }
});
```

Then on the client:

```
Meteor.call('getSomeCollectionCount', function (error, result) {
  if(!error) {
    // add code to be run when count is ready

    console.log('someCollection count: ', result);
  }
});
```

The other way is to use pub-sub or iron router waiton, but if you are just trying to get the count I would not recommend the client subscribing to all 1.7 million documents.